# Unable to debug start my .NET 6 ASP.NET project - Failed to load ASP.NET Core runtime

Tags: asp.net-core

When I use Visual Studio 2022 to create a new project using the ASP.NET Core Empty template, I select the .NET 6.0 (Long Term Support) selection from the Framework dropdown in one of the steps of the New Project Wizard. The project build successfully.

When I go to debug run the project using IIS Express and Edge, it comes up and displays the message

```
HTTP Error 500.31 - Failed to load ASP.NET Core runtime
Common solutions to this issue:
The specified version of Microsoft.NetCore.App or Microsoft.AspNetCore.App was not found.
Specific error detected by ANCM:
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '6.0.8' (x64) was not found. - The following frameworks were found: 2.2.7 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App] 3.1.19 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App] 3.1.28 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App] 5.0.10 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App] 5.0.17 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App] 6.0.4 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App] You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK. The specified framework can be found at: - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=6.0.8&arch=x64&rid=win10-x64
Troubleshooting steps:
Check the system event log for error messages
Enable logging the application process' stdout messages
Attach a debugger to the application process and inspect
For more information visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=2028526
```

I really thought that I had version 6 of the .NET framework installed, so I navidated to the URL referenced in the error message to see if I got some other information that might be useful:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-6.0#50031-ancm-failed-to-find-native-dependencies

It pretty much confirmed that I probably didn't have FW 6 installed. So, I tried to verify this using the following CL command

```
dotnet --info
```

And, the way I read it, it suggests that I do have it installed.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1889]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Y:\>dotnet --info
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   6.0.202
 Commit:    f8a55617d2

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19042
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.202\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 6.0.4
  Commit:  be98e88c76

.NET SDKs installed:
  3.1.422 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.401 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.408 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  6.0.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.19 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.28 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.19 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.28 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.19 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.28 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

To install additional .NET runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Y:\>
```

I wouldn't expect that the wizard would present this version of the FW to me if I didn't have it installed.

But the question remains, if I have it installed, what is the issue? Are there different installation types of the framework? For example, a runtime vs. SDK, or something like that? I'm not sure at this moment where to go next....

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, it said the Microsoft.NetCore.App 6.0.8 is not installed and I found you just install the Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.8, I suggest you could try to install it and try again.

URL:

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0

Image:

[image]

Comment: I fugured I had nothing to lose by trying to install it manually, but the output fromn teh dotnet --info command also shows `6.0.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]` which sugegsts to me that I should have version 6 of the framework installed and I wouldnt expect VS 2022 to present 6.0 in the FW version when creating a new project from a template. I'll try to manually install it using the link you provided...